# SBT Spring JUnit test fails, but build marked as success

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, sbt

I've got a simple unit test that is failing on purpose. The failed test shows up in the output, but the build succeeds with no failed unit tests. A normal unit test without SpringJUnit4ClassRunner fails as expected and the build is marked as fail. What's going on?

Spring: 4.2.6.RELEASE

Test class:

```
import config.TestAppConfig;
import config.TestDataConfig;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestAppConfig.class, TestDataConfig.class})
public class UserTest {
    @Test
    public void testNoDupes() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(null);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[error] Test UserTest.testNoDupes failed: null, took 0.004 sec
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Jun 3, 2016 11:04:32 AM
```

Comment: I was getting similar issue while running cucumber-jvm via junit runner.  In my case after the cucumber tests, sbt runs the scala test runner, but there are no scala-tests and it ignores cucumber failures, and makes the build pass.